# R: Error in array(0, range) : cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'integer'

Tags: arrays, r

I wrote the following function in R. The code takes a character array, and appends a "0" before it in case its length is less than 2.

```
create.array = function(x){
  browser
  y = array(0,range)
  range = 2
  if (nchar(x) == 1){
      x = paste("0",x,sep="")
    }
  for (i in (1:range)){
    y[i] = as.numeric(substr(x,i,i))
  }
  y  
}
create.array("0")
```

Output:

```
Error in array(0, range) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'integer'
```

Comment: What do you intend the `range` "variable" to contain?

Comment: `range` is a primitive (builtin) function in R. This is the origin of your error message.